# Unexpected reserved word 'yield' when running Jest unit tests

Tags: jestjs

I'm using TypeScript and Jest to write unit tests. When I tried to run them, I got the following error messages:

```
Test suite failed to run
    Jest encountered an unexpected token
    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

SyntaxError: C:\..\my\file\name.web.spec.ts: Unexpected reserved word 'yield'.
```

This came from an original TypeScript section like the following:

```js
it("should do things right", () => {
    const payload = { ... };
    await manager.init(payload);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution seems obvious in retrospect when looking at the code, but easy to miss. I just simply needed to make the function async.

```
it("should do things right", async () => {
    const payload = { ... };
    await manager.init(payload);
});
```